# <script> tag does not loads .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I am implementing a web application and trying to load .js file and none of them are loading. I see that GET of this particular file is failing.

This is my folder structure.

```
MyApp
 app
  routes
   routes.js
 bower_components
 node_modules
 public
  index.html
  routes
   routes.js
  controllers
  templates
 app.js
 package.json
```

I am unable to load public/routes/routes.js from public/index.html

below is index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Login Test</title>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/routes/routes.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-view>

  </div>
</div>
```

What am i missing here

Comment: Change `<script src="/routes/routes.js"></script>` to `<script src="routes/routes.js"></script>`

Comment: both scripts are accessing the same URL.. http://localhost:3000/routes/routes.js, I tried this before

Comment: Do you use a framework of some sort? If you're **not**, you should use either `/app/routes/routes.js`, or `/public/routes/routes.js` (you have 2 files named `route.js`?); if you **are** using a framework, you need to tell us which.

Comment: I am using express js framework at the server side scripting and angular in the front. I also tried giving /public/routes/routes.js and this is the url it is accessing to  http://localhost:3000/public/routes/routes.js and the Error is  '404 Not Found'

Comment: Did you try "../app/routes/routes.js"  ?

Comment: I tried all these possibilities and it is 404 not found. I guess there is something in the framework that is giving this problem. How to resolve this.. I am using express 4.10.0 framework.. I have an example which uses 3.x version of the same framework and i see it works and it loads fine..